# Can't convert a number to a float

Tags: python, input, int

I'm trying to solve a homework problem as an extreme novice to python, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I have the code and error message below, hoping that someone can tell me where I went wrong.

The miles input tries 10, 50, then 100. Which works.
Mpg is 20.0. Also works.
gp input is 3.1599, which gives me this error. Not sure why.

```
miles = float(input())  
mpg = float(input())
gp = float(input())
price = (miles*1.0/mpg)*gp
print(price)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in 
    gp = float(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: I guess you meant: `miles = float(input())`?

Comment: Yes, corrected that. Still gives me a callback to line 5.

Comment: Are you sure you are entering the values correctly? Cannot reproduce the error

Comment: The site I'm doing the homework on enters the values automatically. It works for me personally, but when I try to submit it for a grade it gives me the same error message about line 5

Comment: Did you hit newline for the first one instead of entering a number?

Comment: It doesn't allow me to enter the numbers, it automatically places the values into the inputs

Comment: Are you sure this is the intended method of accepting input on the site is by the input() function? If it is, I'd suggest minimizing your example down even more to just accepting the inputs and printing them directly, just to rule out anything else that might not be working as intended.

Comment: I simplified it, however it continues to have the same problem with line 3.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. See below:

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: Works for me as well, but gives me the error described above when I try to submit it. I think I'll have to ask my instructor what the problem is.

Comment: @AlexBurke great. Would you mind upvoting my response? I'm new here and it would help me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EOF error results usually in an online compiler when an input is given by the system but the input reading line is not at the right place to read it. Read the sample input syntax again and try, or give input inside code.

You can use try catch block to solve this problem.

In your code you did not take miles as int in line 1, but you try to multiply it with float in line 6.

```
try:
  miles = float(input())   
  print('Enter miles per gallon:')
  mpg = float(input())
  print('Enter the gas price:')
  gp = float(input())
  price = (miles*1.0/mpg)*gp  
  print(price)
except:
  pass
```

Comment: Changed miles to int(input()) and then int(float(input())), still gives me the same error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    gp = float(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: try:
----your code----
----your code----
----your code----
except EOFError as e : pass

Comment: in simple use try  and except block and pass in expect block

Comment: Don't understand how to do that at all, and the syntax needs to be exact in order for it to be graded properly, so when I add anything extra into my code it rejects it from submission.

Comment: hi please have a look on my answer again i just added try expect block just try to run that code once hope it will work

Comment: It got rid of the error, thank you. However my output is Enter miles per gallon:
Enter the gas price: and it's supposed to be Enter miles per gallon:Enter the gas price:1.57995 7.89975 63.198 I don't know why it isn't printing price, I think I'll have to ask my instructor about that part.

Comment: yes sure man please let me know whatever your instructor will suggest you. so i can improve myself

Comment: mpg = float(input('Enter miles per gallon:'))
gp = float(input('Enter the gas price:'))
price = (10*1.0/mpg)*gp
print(price)
price = (50*1.0/mpg)*gp
print(price)
price = (400*1.0/mpg)*gp
print(price)  It was as simple as that, guess I overthought the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
`mpg = float(input('Enter miles per gallon:'))
 gp = float(input('Enter the gas price:'))
 price = (10*1.0/mpg)*gp print(price) 
 price = (50*1.0/mpg)*gp print(price) 
 price = (400*1.0/mpg)*gp print(price)`
```

This was the answer, solved