# Runtime error: EOF when reading a line(in line 18)

Tags: python

## Given a n x m matrix of integers, replace every element with sum of elements present on its right excluding current element (in current row only).

```
def sum(arr):
    for i in range(n):
        
        for j in range(0,m):
            s=0
            for k in range(j+1,m):
                s=s+arr[i][k]
            arr[i][j]=s
            
    for i in range(n):
         for j in range(0,m):
                print(arr[i][j],end=' ')
         
         print()
                
str=input().split()
n,m=int(str[0]),int(str[1])
arr=[[int(j) for j in input().split()] for i in range(n)] #EOF error in j.
sum(arr)
```

Comment: What do you provide as input?

Comment: it's working for me given input in correct format.

Comment: 1 2(in first line) 2 3(in second line)  #In this way, sample test cases are perfectly working but while submitting it is showing runtime  error.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105356/cant-convert-a-number-to-a-float#comment102601915_58105356, seems they were having a very similar problem.